# Grails: Join on two columns of the same table

Tags: grails, hql, grails-orm, criteria

How can I transform this SQL Query to a criteria or HQL query in grails

```
select  distinct(x.id) 
FROM y INNER JOIN x ON y.x_id =x.id  OR y.x2_id=x.id
```

where x_id and x2_id are foreign keys for x table

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick,

```
select distinct(y.id) from Y y 
left join y.x1 x1
left join y.x2 x2
```

If not, then

```
select distinct(y.id) from Y y 
full join y.x1 x1
full join y.x2 x2
```

If they are unconnected, try this

```
select distinct(x.id) from X x, Y y 
where y.xId1 = x.id or y.xId2 = x.id
```

**Note:**  It would be helpful, if you can share both domain classes. Btw, I'm not having the environment, so can't try these.

Comment: Hello thank you fro your reply I already tried this befor and i got an     org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException
Message
    Path expected for join!

Comment: See my addendum.